# how to use lookaround regex in this latex example

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

the latex sample is as follows:

> `$F=K$`,balalalala,balablal `Bi$_x$Sb$_{1-x}$`，balabla `$abcd$` balabala

What I want to match is inline math expressions like `$F=K$`, `$abcd$`, while not those expressions with "_" after "$", like `$_x$` and `$_{1-x}$`

So I write regex expression like this

```
\$[^_][^\$]+\$(?!_)
```

I add `(?!_)` because `$Sb$` in the middle of `Bi$_x$Sb$_{1-x}$` should not be considered as an math expression.

But the code is not working properly. It returns two expression
`$F=K$` and `$，balabla $`.

What is the right regex expression for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

your desired match needs a Lookbehind regex, somthing like:

```
\$[^$]+\$(?<!\$_[^$]+)
```

but we know that regex inside could not use `+` or `*` (must be fix-length), so the above regex is invalid.

I suggest to process the text in 2-pass. in first pass remove any `$_xxx$` pattern :

```
perl -ne 's/(\$_[^\$]+\$)//g;print;'
```

and then match your desired pattern:

```
grep -oP '\$[^$]+\$'
```

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry! I found that my original question contains mistakes, because the system automatically changed the latex math expression into math expression. I have fixed my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: @bjb568  طاهر see the mistaken question I originally gived. So he gived a wrong answer. It is my fault.